# How do I use Google App Engine Python 3 Blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am working on a Google App Engine project in Python 3 that needs to allow users to upload files larger than the 32gb limit.  Ideally, I would like these files to end up in my bucket as well.  I have found a guide for Python 2, but it (A) does not tell you how to import blobstore to the project and (B) seems to indicate that this method is intended for python 2.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

In the Python 3.7 runtime, Blobstore is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#changes_to_the_app_engine_standard_environment) in favor of using Google Cloud Storage.

> The Python 3.7 runtime in the App Engine standard environment does not use the App Engine SDK to provide access to service functionality, unlike the Python 2.7 runtime, which does. Instead when using the Python 3.7 runtime, you should use the Google Cloud managed services and/or third party services that meet your needs.
>
> **Blobstore**
> To store and retrieve data, use Cloud Storage through the Google Cloud client libraries. To get started, see Using Cloud Storage.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage) is the main tutorial on how to use Google Cloud Storage.

---

[Uploading objects into Cloud Storage using Python](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python)
[Uploading Objects Guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects)
[Objects Insert Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert)

> This method accepts uploaded object data with the following characteristics:
>
> Maximum file size: 5 TB

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though this doesn't really tell me how to let users upload files.  Is there a tutorial for going around the 32gb limit on POST requests?

Comment: See edits but this method does not have a 32 gb limit, cloud storage objects that are uploaded using the insert method have a 5 TB maximum size. @eric